# Truncate integer to specific number of digits?

Tags: sql, postgresql, integer, truncate

We want an SQL (not PL/pgSQL) function that given a random positive integer of any size, returns an integer between 0 & 999999 inclusive. The return value should retain as much as possible the randomness of the argument.

Comment: If you pass 42 to the function twice, should it return the same value both times? If you pass 42, and I pass 42, should we get the same value?

Answer (score 0):

In PostgresSQL:

set seed sets the random for the next time you call the random function:

```
setseed (arg)
```

This statement will generate a number in the range [0:999999] inclusive

```
SELECT floor(random()*(999999-0+1))+10;
```

In Python:

```
import random
def get_rand_int(arg)
    random.seed(arg)
    return random.randrange(0,100000)
```

Something to keep in mind when using random

" The Mersenne Twister is one of the most extensively tested random number generators in existence. However, being completely deterministic, it is not suitable for all purposes, and is completely unsuitable for cryptographic purposes." https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html?highlight=random#random.random

In SQL:

This will return a floored integer between 999999 and 0 using [seed] as a seed value.

```
SELECT FLOOR(RAND([seed])*(999999-0));
```

Comment: Nice! Now, can you give an answer to this question in SQL?

Comment: Sorry, didn't pay attention to the tag, hope this works for you.

Comment: @J.Clark: PostgreSQL doesn't have a function named `rand()`. The function it *does* have doesn't take an argument. Maybe it's time to pay attention to the tags.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' The question says "We want an SQL (not PL/pgSQL) function..."

Comment: @J.Clark: And the tags include "postgresql", not Python, not "tsql", and not  "sql-server".  PL/pgSQL is PostgreSQL's procedural language, not PostgreSQL's SQL dialect. Your SQL statement won't run on *any* Standard SQL dbms; it will throw multiple syntax errors on PostgreSQL.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' Thanks for the feedback, would you say the edit answers the question?

Comment: @J.Clark: The SQL statement `SELECT floor(random()*(999999-0+1))+10;` answers the question, but it's wrong. The Python and T-SQL code isn't relevant to the question.